# How to set min and max datetime dynamic on input type='datetime-local' or Textmode='Datetimelocal' via jQuery or C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to set  dynamic min and max date time last three days enable remaining days disable ) below c# code not working

```
TextBox1.Attributes["min"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss ");
```

html code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TextMode="DateTimeLocal" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: thank advance  please can any one help on this.

Comment: As far as I understand, this is a textbox not DatePicker or something, right? So what do you mean by set min datetime to textbox? What do you want to achieve here? We need more information to help you.

Comment: yes textbox but type datetimelocal. So here i want to show only three days enable like min attribute -3 days and today is max attribute .The output is like i can able select only three days today,yesterday and daybefore yesterday

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an extra white-space at the end of `ToString` and it causes a problem.

So change:

```
.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss ");
```

to as follow, it should work.

```
.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
```